# Is 'resource' key word in FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

We encountered strange behavior of FactoryGirl. Here is the definition of the commonx_log:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :commonx_log, :class => 'Commonx::Log' do
    log "My log"
    resource_id 1
    resource "MyString"
    last_updated_by_id 1
  end
end
```

Here is the validation in `log` model:

```
validates_presence_of :log, :resource, :resource_id
```

The following rspec would pass:

```
it "should be OK" do
  c = FactoryGirl.build(:commonx_log, :last_updated_by_id => 2)
  c.should be_valid
end
```

However as soon as we are trying to assign value to `resource` and `resource_id`:

```
c = FactoryGirl.build(:commonx_log, :resource => 'resource')
```

there is an error:

```
1) Commonx::Log should be OK
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mc.should be_valid←[0m
       ←[31mexpected #<Commonx::Log id: nil, log: "My log", resource_id: nil, resource: "resource", last_updated_by_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> to be valid
, but got errors: Resource can't be blank←[0m
```

What could cause the error? Is it `resource` key work in Factory Girl? Thanks for the help.

UPDATE:

The solution we have is to rename `resource` to `resource_name` in log model. After that, we can treat `resource_name` as regular field and do validation. When `resource_id` and `resource` appear in log model, rails assumes that `resource` is in certain type of  `association` (see post by Ryan Bigg below). This assumption by rails automatically put `resource_id` and `resource` in validation and does not allow assigning value to `resource_id` (`resource_id` should be from association by default). This assumption causes problem in our app (can not assign `resource_id`) and we rename `resource` to break this tie of association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is because you're validating the presence of the association. You don't need to do that at all. Remove `resource` from your `validates_presence_of` line.

Is there an actual case in your application where log entries can be created without resources? If not, I wouldn't be too concerned with the validations of these attributes. If you're *super* worried about `resource_id` being null, then placing a database constraint on `resource_id` would be the appropriate way to go.

Comment: After removing resource from validates_presence_of, factory girl does not causes error. But not quite understand how rails works here. We do need to validate the presence of resource in log model. Log model is in an rails engine and is designed to be shared by multiple resources. We need to pass resource as params and that's why we want to validate if the resource is presented when saving a log in case if the resource params is forgot to be passed in.

Comment: Somehow still can't assign value to resource and resource_id in log in factory girl by  log = FactoryGirl.create(:commonx_log, :resource_id => lead.id, :resource => 'projectx/projects'). They are all nil.

Answer (score 0):

`resource` is a rails keyword used for routing, perhaps that is what causes you trouble?

Comment: The error is caused by creating data with factory girl in rspec, not by get 'index'.